# Eliminar "," al final de una lista. Y crear una tabla de "Excluidos"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, reactjs

## [ALETORIZADOR DE GRUPOS]

En el código que se encuentra en el enlace que dejaré abajo se encuentra el siguiente programa:
[image]

En este podrás especificar primeramente el **numero de grupos** y seguidamente el **número de personas por grupo**:

Al indicar los grupos y personas por grupo y hacer **click** en el botón aparecerá un **alert** en el cual podremos **indicar los nombres separados por comas**:
[image]

Al imprimir los nombres que contiene el array me aparece la coma final por la que he hecho `.split(',')` *[Recuadro Verde]*,y tengo que crear un grupo aparte para las personas que sobran de esa lista *[Recuadro Rojo y Recuadro Resultado Morado]* pero me esta dando problemas.
[image]

**RECURSO:**  [Código en **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonioVladimir/4pus6jyt/4/)

**Gracias por su tiempo y su ayuda**.

Comment: Podrías compartir el array y lo que has intentado, por favor

Comment: @Samsepi esta en el código del enlace que pasé, gracias por mostrar interés!

Comment: sólo quieres quitar esa última ','?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo sí, y añadir una función para que me guarden los nombres del array que sobren en una tabla excluidos, gracias!

Comment: Añado fotos, para explicarlo

Comment: @L.Ronquillo  expliqué mejor el tema.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo explicado!

Answer (score 1):

Esta parte:

```
let innerText = "<br><h4 class='todos-nombres'> TODOS LOS NOMBRES </h4><br>";
for (let i = 0; i < nuevoArray.length; i++) {
  innerText += nuevoArray[i] + ",";
}
innerText += "<br>" + "<br>" + "\n";
```

Se puede reemplazar con:

```
let innerText = `
  <br /><h4 class="todos-nombres">TODOS LOS NOMBRES</h4><br />
  ${nuevoArray.join(', ')}
  <br /><br />
`;
```

Así desaparecerá esa coma al final.

#### Bonus

Tienes que acostumbrarte ahora que estás empezando a **escribir código limpio, entendible, manejable**. Prefiere siempre un código modular frente a una sola función enorme que haga todo. Lee sobre principios SOLID.

Así podría verse tu código modularizando:

```js
function printPeople(people) {
    const output = document.getElementById('personas');
  output.innerHTML = `
        <br><h4 class='todos-nombres'> PERSONAS </h4><br>
        <code>${people.join(', ')}</code>
        <br />
    `;
}

function printGroups(groups) {
    const output = document.getElementById('gruposFinales');
  output.innerHTML = `
        <br><h4 class='todos-nombres'> GRUPOS </h4><br>
        ${
        groups.map(group => (`
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Personas</th></tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                ${
                  group.map(person => `<p>${person}</p>`)
                }
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      `))
    }
        <br /><br />
    `.replace(/,/g, '');
}

function suffleList(array) {
        const clone = [...array];
    for (let i = clone.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = clone[i];
        clone[i] = clone[j];
        clone[j] = temp;
    }
    return clone;
}

/* Utilitary of @sospedra - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29645164/10670707 */
const chunk = (target, size) => {
  return target.reduce((memo, value, index) => {
    if (index % (target.length / size) == 0 && index !== 0) memo.push([])
    memo[memo.length - 1].push(value)
    return memo
  }, [[]])
}


function Grupos() {
    const names = prompt("Nombres: ").split(",");

    let peoplePerGroup = Number.parseInt(
        document.getElementById("personasDelGrupo").value,
      10
    );
    
    const randomizedPeople = suffleList(names);
    const groups = chunk(randomizedPeople, names.length / peoplePerGroup);
    
    printPeople(names);
    printGroups(groups);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Major+Mono+Display&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}

.title {
    padding-top: 66px;
    font-family   : 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-align    : center;
    line-height   : 40px;
    color         : rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight   : 200;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h5{
    font-size: medium;
}
table{
    padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-table;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
table th {
  font-weight: bolder;
}
code {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #eee;
}
#grupos{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    padding: 10px;
    outline:none;
    border: 0;
    border: 1px solid #011627;
}
#grupos::placeholder{
    outline:none;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;

}
#grupos:hover{
    border: 1px solid #011627;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #011627;
}
#personasDelGrupo{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    padding: 10px;
    outline:none;
    border: 0;
    border: 1px solid #011627;
}
#personasDelGrupo::placeholder{
    outline:none;
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#personasDelGrupo:hover{
    border: 1px solid #011627;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #011627;
}


.boton{
    border: 2px #fff;
    color:white;
    background: #011627;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #011627;
}
.boton:hover{
    transition: 0.7s;
    background-color: #fff;
    color : #191919;
    border: 1px solid #011627;
}

.posicion {
    padding-top: 33px;
    display   : table;
    height    : 100%;
    margin    : 0 auto;
    
}
.tablas{
    padding: 20px;
    margin:  20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.el-contenedor {
    display       : table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="title"> GROUP RANDOMIZER </h1>

  <div class="posicion">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="el-contenedor">
            <input id="personasDelGrupo" placeholder="Personas por grupo">
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Crear Grupos" class="boton" onclick="Grupos()">
            <br>
            <div id="personas"></div>
            <div id="gruposFinales"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: la cosa es que requiero de la tabla excluidos, con ello el usuario podra poner todos los nombres que quiera.